# PHP Create JSON Array from PHP Array Dynamically

Tags: php, arrays

I have a form that users can enter multiple Task IDs in a box then click submit to search for these. I'm creating an array of these like this:

```
$taskIDsInput = $_GET['taskID'];
$taskIDsArray = explode( "\r", $taskIDsInput);
```

which creates an array that looks like this:

```
Array 
(
[0] => 60092296
[1] => 60092323
)
```

For each of these IDs I need to construct a line like the following:

```
$findTasksRequest['query'][0]['TaskNumber'] = '=='.$taskIDsInput;
```

I need to increase the `[0]` by one for each taskID (it will be used to create json so needs to start at 0) and also replace the `$taskIDsInput` with the value for each taskID contained in the array. I've tried many variations here but can't work out the correct PHP syntax here and whether I should be using a `foreach` loop or something else.

My latest attempt looks like this:

```
    for($i = 0; $i < count($taskIDsArray); $i++) { 
    ${'findTasksRequest[\'query\']' . ($i+1)}['TaskNumber'] = '=='.$taskIDsArray[$i];
}
```

which isn't working correctly.

Comment: OMG foreach ($taskIDsArray as $i=>$value) $taskIDsArray[$i] = '=='.$value;

Comment: or well $findTasksRequest['query'][$i]['TaskNumber'] = '=='.$value;